# How to set background color of a UIImageView from a UICollectionView cell

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uicollectionview, uicolor, uicollectionviewcell

I have not used UICollectionView much so this may not be possible, but never hurts to ask :)

Each cell is set up as a different color.

What I want to do is tap on a cell and push to another UIViewController that will contain a UIImageView of the same color that was selected.

Right now I can change the color of the second UIViewController's View, but not of the UIImageView within it.

Here's some of my code:

```
 - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     [collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

     ImageViewController * imageVC = [[ImageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ImageViewController" bundle:nil];

     self.flatColor = [self colorForRow:indexPath.row];

     [self.navigationController pushViewController:imageVC animated:YES];

     imageVC.colorImageView.backgroundColor = _flatColor;
 }

 - (UIColor *)colorForRow:(NSInteger)row
 {
     UIColor *color;

     switch (row)
     {
         case 0:
             color = [UIColor redColor];
             break;
         case 2:
             color = [UIColor greenColor];
             break;
         case 4:
             color = [UIColor blueColor];
             break;
         default:
             color = [UIColor yellowColor];
             break;
     }

     return color;
 }
```

EDIT:

Fixed the issue.

I had to rearrange some of the code.  The new viewController needs to be completely loaded first and then change the backgroundColor of the UIImageView

Answer (score 0):

Try following code.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     [collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

     ImageViewController * imageVC = [[ImageViewController alloc]    initWithNibName:@"ImageViewController" bundle:nil];

     self.flatColor = [self colorForRow:indexPath.row];

     // This does not work

    [imageVC.colorImageView setBackgroundColor:_flatColor];

    //imageVC.colorImageView.backgroundColor = _flatColor;

     // This works
     //imageVC.view.backgroundColor = _flatColor;

     [self.navigationController pushViewController:imageVC animated:YES];
 }
```